# Why this server program that written in Go hangs?

Tags: go, tcp, goroutine

This TCP server program does broadcast Candle(It represents that stock prices of Open, High, Low, Close, Datetime in for each specific period) data to clients.

I don't know but This program does hang sometimes.

The server passed by Candle data from a given channel then try to broadcast to connected clients.

Data format of this program are constructed from Candle of JSON representation and these size.
First 8 bytes represents length of the JSON string followed by actual JSON payload.

The hang looks like caused by Read blocking somewhere.
Strangely, first of some candles works correctly, but it hangs suddenly.

Client Program is written for test, so `data_csv` is csv string data of bunch of (almost 400s) candles.

How I can fix this hang?

##### Edit:

The following is a output of `debug/pprof/block`.
How I can investigate from this output?

```
--- contention:
cycles/second=1696768617
13635783453 2 @ 0x448dc8 0x66f576 0x66fc85 0x61eeaf 0x620849 0x621b5b 0x61dbd7 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x66f575    net/http/pprof.sleep+0x95       /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:98
#   0x66fc84    net/http/pprof.Profile+0x324        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:142
#   0x61eeae    net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP+0x2e /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084
#   0x620848    net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP+0x148    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2462
#   0x621b5a    net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP+0x43a  /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916
#   0x61dbd6    net/http.(*conn).serve+0x5d6        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966

2547801781 121 @ 0x407878 0x673ba5 0x468561
#   0x407877    runtime.chanrecv2+0x17              /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/chan.go:445
#   0x673ba4    investment.(*CandleServer[...]).Run.func2+0x184 /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/candle_server.go:46

21222953 278 @ 0x406b1d 0x6738a8 0x468561
#   0x406b1c    runtime.chansend1+0x1c  /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/chan.go:144
#   0x6738a7    main.main.func3+0x107   /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:73

5721316 77 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x673b5d 0x673b06 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82          /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64               /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a               /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74               /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x673b5c    fmt.Println+0x13c               /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x673b05    investment.(*CandleServer[...]).Run.func2+0xe5  /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/candle_server.go:63

4184159 2 @ 0x407838 0x665885 0x66fc8a 0x61eeaf 0x620849 0x621b5b 0x61dbd7 0x468561
#   0x407837    runtime.chanrecv1+0x17          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/chan.go:440
#   0x665884    runtime/pprof.StopCPUProfile+0xa4   /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:830
#   0x66fc89    net/http/pprof.Profile+0x329        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go:143
#   0x61eeae    net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP+0x2e /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084
#   0x620848    net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP+0x148    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2462
#   0x621b5a    net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP+0x43a  /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916
#   0x61dbd6    net/http.(*conn).serve+0x5d6        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966

2211530 1 @ 0x448dc8 0x57695b 0x574ada 0x562abb 0x565aca 0x56604b 0x621cd8 0x6729a5 0x672975 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x57695a    net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr+0x51a  /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:325
#   0x574ad9    net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList+0x679  /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288
#   0x562aba    net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList+0x41a   /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221
#   0x565ac9    net.(*ListenConfig).Listen+0x89     /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:626
#   0x56604a    net.Listen+0x4a             /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:712
#   0x621cd7    net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe+0x57  /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2964
#   0x6729a4    net/http.ListenAndServe+0x44        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:3222
#   0x672974    main.main.func1+0x14            /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:21

1867943 1 @ 0x448dc8 0x5835aa 0x577d88 0x56e53d 0x5771ff 0x55ee5b 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407              /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x5835a9    net.cgoLookupIP+0x1a9               /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:228
#   0x577d87    net.(*Resolver).lookupIP+0x127          /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:96
#   0x56e53c    net.glob..func1+0x3c                /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23
#   0x5771fe    net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1+0x9e     /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:319
#   0x55ee5a    internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall+0x3a  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95

1024267 1 @ 0x448dc8 0x57695b 0x574ada 0x562abb 0x563a48 0x5635ba 0x5635bb 0x672dd1 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x57695a    net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr+0x51a  /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:325
#   0x574ad9    net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList+0x679  /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288
#   0x562aba    net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList+0x41a   /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221
#   0x563a47    net.(*Dialer).DialContext+0x447     /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:406
#   0x5635b9    net.(*Dialer).Dial+0x79         /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:351
#   0x5635ba    net.Dial+0x7a               /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:319
#   0x672dd0    main.main+0x410             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:77
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

990165 1 @ 0x448dc8 0x57695b 0x574ada 0x562abb 0x565aca 0x56604b 0x67413c 0x6739f4 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407              /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x57695a    net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr+0x51a      /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:325
#   0x574ad9    net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList+0x679      /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288
#   0x562aba    net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList+0x41a       /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221
#   0x565ac9    net.(*ListenConfig).Listen+0x89         /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:626
#   0x56604a    net.Listen+0x4a                 /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:712
#   0x67413b    investment.(*CandleServer[...]).Run+0x13b   /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/candle_server.go:67
#   0x6739f3    main.main.func2+0xb3                /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:66

635103 3 @ 0x448dc8 0x564529 0x563d11 0x5635ba 0x5635bb 0x672dd1 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x564528    net.(*sysDialer).dialParallel+0x4e8 /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:493
#   0x563d10    net.(*Dialer).DialContext+0x710     /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:426
#   0x5635b9    net.(*Dialer).Dial+0x79         /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:351
#   0x5635ba    net.Dial+0x7a               /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:319
#   0x672dd0    main.main+0x410             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:77
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

247248 59 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x672fcf 0x672f83 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x672fce    fmt.Println+0x60e           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x672f82    main.main+0x5c2             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:87
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

212347 58 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x673c85 0x673be6 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82          /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64               /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a               /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74               /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x673c84    fmt.Println+0x264               /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x673be5    investment.(*CandleServer[...]).Run.func2+0x1c5 /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/candle_server.go:48

104006 7 @ 0x478b0c 0x617d35 0x61cf67 0x61dc1a 0x468561
#   0x478b0b    sync.(*Cond).Wait+0x8b              /usr/lib/go/src/sync/cond.go:56
#   0x617d34    net/http.(*connReader).abortPendingRead+0xb4    /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:720
#   0x61cf66    net/http.(*response).finishRequest+0x86     /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1633
#   0x61dc19    net/http.(*conn).serve+0x619            /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:1972

100385 28 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x6731b9 0x67316d 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x6731b8    fmt.Println+0x7f8           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x67316c    main.main+0x7ac             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:101
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

75004 2 @ 0x448dc8 0x56de86 0x468561
#   0x448dc7    runtime.selectgo+0x407      /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/select.go:509
#   0x56de85    net.(*netFD).connect.func2+0x85 /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:118

53125 17 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x673027 0x672fd0 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x673026    fmt.Println+0x666           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x672fcf    main.main+0x60f             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:88
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

34085 1 @ 0x407838 0x56df91 0x56db0f 0x57cd74 0x57c8d2 0x5757d8 0x57f425 0x57f319 0x56556b 0x564eb2 0x564a32 0x468561
#   0x407837    runtime.chanrecv1+0x17              /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/chan.go:440
#   0x56df90    net.(*netFD).connect.func1+0x50         /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:106
#   0x56db0e    net.(*netFD).connect+0x86e          /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:165
#   0x57cd73    net.(*netFD).dial+0x393             /usr/lib/go/src/net/sock_posix.go:149
#   0x57c8d1    net.socket+0x2b1                /usr/lib/go/src/net/sock_posix.go:70
#   0x5757d7    net.internetSocket+0xf7             /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock_posix.go:142
#   0x57f424    net.(*sysDialer).doDialTCP+0xa4         /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:65
#   0x57f318    net.(*sysDialer).dialTCP+0x58           /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:61
#   0x56556a    net.(*sysDialer).dialSingle+0x28a       /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:583
#   0x564eb1    net.(*sysDialer).dialSerial+0x311       /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:551
#   0x564a31    net.(*sysDialer).dialParallel.func1+0x91    /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:471

23477 6 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x673135 0x6730ec 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x673134    fmt.Println+0x774           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x6730eb    main.main+0x72b             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:99
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

22797 1 @ 0x47a9f3 0x47a9c7 0x578ab1 0x578a95 0x57c7af 0x5757d8 0x57f985 0x565ccf 0x56604b 0x621cd8 0x6729a5 0x672975 0x468561
#   0x47a9f2    sync.(*Mutex).Lock+0x52         /usr/lib/go/src/sync/mutex.go:81
#   0x47a9c6    sync.(*Once).doSlow+0x26        /usr/lib/go/src/sync/once.go:64
#   0x578ab0    sync.(*Once).Do+0x30            /usr/lib/go/src/sync/once.go:59
#   0x578a94    net.listenerBacklog+0x14        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:377
#   0x57c7ae    net.socket+0x18e            /usr/lib/go/src/net/sock_posix.go:57
#   0x5757d7    net.internetSocket+0xf7         /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock_posix.go:142
#   0x57f984    net.(*sysListener).listenTCP+0x84   /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:168
#   0x565cce    net.(*ListenConfig).Listen+0x28e    /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:639
#   0x56604a    net.Listen+0x4a             /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:712
#   0x621cd7    net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe+0x57  /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:2964
#   0x6729a4    net/http.ListenAndServe+0x44        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/server.go:3222
#   0x672974    main.main.func1+0x14            /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:21

14926 1 @ 0x407838 0x56df91 0x56da58 0x57cd74 0x57c8d2 0x5757d8 0x57f425 0x57f319 0x56556b 0x564eb2 0x564a32 0x468561
#   0x407837    runtime.chanrecv1+0x17              /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/chan.go:440
#   0x56df90    net.(*netFD).connect.func1+0x50         /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:106
#   0x56da57    net.(*netFD).connect+0x7b7          /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:162
#   0x57cd73    net.(*netFD).dial+0x393             /usr/lib/go/src/net/sock_posix.go:149
#   0x57c8d1    net.socket+0x2b1                /usr/lib/go/src/net/sock_posix.go:70
#   0x5757d7    net.internetSocket+0xf7             /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock_posix.go:142
#   0x57f424    net.(*sysDialer).doDialTCP+0xa4         /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:65
#   0x57f318    net.(*sysDialer).dialTCP+0x58           /usr/lib/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:61
#   0x56556a    net.(*sysDialer).dialSingle+0x28a       /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:583
#   0x564eb1    net.(*sysDialer).dialSerial+0x311       /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:551
#   0x564a31    net.(*sysDialer).dialParallel.func1+0x91    /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:471

14739 4 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x672f4f 0x672f06 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x672f4e    fmt.Println+0x58e           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x672f05    main.main+0x545             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:85
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250

8891 2 @ 0x4aa032 0x4ab552 0x4ab563 0x4afe05 0x4afdfb 0x4b6315 0x672f05 0x672eba 0x4393d2 0x468561
#   0x4aa031    internal/poll.(*fdMutex).rwlock+0xd1    /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:154
#   0x4ab551    internal/poll.(*FD).writeLock+0x71  /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:239
#   0x4ab562    internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x82      /usr/lib/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:370
#   0x4afe04    os.(*File).write+0x64           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file_posix.go:48
#   0x4afdfa    os.(*File).Write+0x5a           /usr/lib/go/src/os/file.go:176
#   0x4b6314    fmt.Fprintln+0x74           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:265
#   0x672f04    fmt.Println+0x544           /usr/lib/go/src/fmt/print.go:274
#   0x672eb9    main.main+0x4f9             /home/kiyugad/money/src/investment/test/cs.go:84
#   0x4393d1    runtime.main+0x211          /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
```

##### Server code:

```
package investment

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

type Candle struct {
    Count    int       `json:"Count,omitempty"`
    Open     float64   `json:"Open"`
    Close    float64   `json:"Close"`
    Low      float64   `json:"Low"`
    High     float64   `json:"High"`
    Datetime time.Time `json:"Datetime"`
}


type Servable interface {
    kabucom3.PositionsSuccess | Candle
}

func ByteLength(b []byte) ([]byte, int) { // util function that add size of JSON string bytes as prefix of JSON bytes.  
    buff := make([]byte, 8)
    b_len := len(b)
    b_len64 := uint64(b_len)
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
        buff[i] = byte((b_len64 >> ((7 - i) * 8))) & byte(0xff)
    }
    buff = append(buff, b...)
    return buff, b_len
}

type CandleServer[T Servable] struct {
    Conns *sync.Map
    C     chan T
}

func (t *CandleServer[T]) Run(addr string, port int) {
    defer func() {
        t.Conns.Range(func(k, v any) bool {
            c := k.(*net.Conn)
            (*c).Close()
            return true
        })
    }()

    go func() { // goroutine for broadcasting.
        var c int = 0
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-t.C:
                c += 1
                fmt.Println("candle_server", "case", c)
                b, err := json.Marshal(v)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("hang ", err)
                }
                result_buff, _ := ByteLength(b)
                t.Conns.Range(func(k, v any) bool {
                    c := k.(*net.Conn)
                    _, err := (*c).Write(result_buff)
                    if err != nil {
                        (*c).Close()
                        t.Conns.Delete(k)
                    }
                    return true
                })
                fmt.Println("candle_server", "after range")
            }
        }
    }()

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr+":"+strconv.Itoa(port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Listen Error", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Accept Error", err)
        }
        t.Conns.Store(&conn, struct{}{})
    }

}

func NewCandleServer[T Servable](c chan T) *CandleServer[T] {
    return &CandleServer[T]{C: c, Conns: &sync.Map{}}
}
```

---

##### Client Program:

```
func main() {
    data_buf := make([]byte, 1024*1024)
    server_addr := "localhost"
    port := 33333
    port_str := "33333"
    JST := time.FixedZone("JST", 9*60*60)
    cs := make([]Candle, 0, 200)
    newline_sep := strings.Split(data_csv, "\n")
    for _, v := range newline_sep {
        var c Candle
        comma_sep := strings.Split(v, ",")
        date_str := comma_sep[0] + " " + comma_sep[1]
        date, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006/01/02 15:04", date_str, JST)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c.Datetime = date
        open, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[2], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        high, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[3], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        low, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[4], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        clo, err := strconv.ParseFloat(comma_sep[5], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c.Open = open
        c.Close = clo
        c.High = high
        c.Low = low
        cs = append(cs, c)
    }
    num_candle := len(cs)
    fmt.Println("num_candle ", num_candle)
    candle_chan := make(chan Candle)
    go func(server_chan chan Candle) {
        s := NewCandleServer(server_chan)
        s.Run(server_addr, port)
    }(candle_chan)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
        for _, v := range cs {
            candle_chan <- v
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", server_addr+":"+port_str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("client connection err:", err)
    }
    i := 0
    size_buffer := make([]byte, 8)
    for i < num_candle {
        fmt.Println(i)
        fmt.Println("Start of read")
        _, err := conn.Read(size_buffer)
        fmt.Println("end of read")
        fmt.Println(size_buffer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("size buffer read error:", err)
        }
        var size uint64 = 0
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            size |= uint64(size_buffer[0]) << (8 * (7 - j))
        }
        if int(size) > len(data_buf) {
            data_buf = make([]byte, size)
        }
        fmt.Println("read hang before")
        _, err = conn.Read(data_buf)
        fmt.Println("read hang")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("payload read error:", err)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    wg.Wait()
    if i != num_candle {
        _ = fmt.Errorf("something Error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("All of candles have been read successfully!!")
}
```

Comment: Enable [pprof](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof) and look at the goroutine blocking profile (/debug/pprof/block) to figure out where your program is blocked.

Comment: @Peter I have been added pprof block profile but I dont know where cause blocking.